# How to correctly require types from dependencies in typescript?

Tags: typescript, npm, dependencies, yarnpkg

I have a question regarding resolving types in my project. So basically I have `packageA -> packageB-v1 -> packageC-v1`, and I would like to use a type declared in `packageC-v1` within `packageA`.

All packages are created by myself, and they are all typescript packages that generate declaration files by setting `declaration: true` in `tsconfig.json` file, they each expose multiple `*.d.ts` files in their `dist` folder. There is no corresponding `@types/*` package for types.

In this case, how should I import types correctly? So far I've tried:

1. `import SomeType from 'packageB-v1/node_modules/packageC-v1/dist/SomeType'`. This works, but I don't like that `packageA` needs to know where `packageC` is installed as it could change depends on package manage tool (npm/yarn), or the install orders (See https://medium.com/learnwithrahul/understanding-npm-dependency-resolution-84a24180901b). I've seen issues that due to different versions of `packageC`, the types are not the same and `tsc` is not ok with it. That could happen when there is another dependency like `packageA -> packageB-v1 -> packageBB-v1 -> packageC-v2`, where npm will install `packageC-v2` instead of `packageC-v1` under `packageB/node_modules`.
2. First export the necessary types `SomeType` from `packageB-v1` by `export SomeType from 'packageC-v1'`, then from packageA I can `import SomeType from 'packageB-v1'`. This works too, however, this also means `packageB-v1` is on the hook to re-export *all* types from *all* of its dependencies (there could be many of them) that its consumers *may* need. That is not usually possible. Also, I've heard re-export may generate different types depends on each case.
3. In `packageA`'s `package.json` file, add the dependency to `packageC-v1` explicitly, even it's actually not directly depend on it. So we could use `import SomeType from 'packageC-v1/SomeType`. Unfortunately, this won't work either as we may have another dependency chain like `packageA -> packageD-v1 -> packageC-v2`. In that case, which `packageC` version we should install under `packageA`? This approach is bad also because even though typescript won't actually include `packageC` in generated JS bundle from `packageA` for using interfaces only, it may do that for enums.

The last way I haven't try is to create my own `@types/packageC-v1` and publish it (and my other ts packages). However if I am writing these packages for a private org, that means we need to maintain an internal types repository, as well as maintain the paired versions of packages and types associate with them. Even if I managed to do that, I can still see many issues with this approach in terms of version mismatch, global declaration conflict, or namescope conflict (it is also true in the `DefinetelyTyped/types` approach).

I am not sure if these make sense to you, and really need some bits of advice here.

Comment: I am even start to think, typescript's approach by creating the type declaration files separately from the JS bundles may be wrong... Javascript should support types in some ways (for example, annotation) natively. I started to see why people may still use JSDoc over TS.

Comment: I think there is really no good solutions other than what @artem posted below. Otherwise, the consumers need to directly depend on the package. That is because enums in typescript will be transpiled to JS code, and if consumers want to use it, it's no difference to use the source code. For interfaces, we may be able to re-export it, but we should also ask consumers why they want to use the interface from the libraries dependency. Usually there will be an easier way to not use them but to use API from our library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a triviality: if a package `A` needs something from package `C`, then `C` by definition is a direct dependency of `A`.

You say you have a reason for not including `C` in dependencies of `A`

> we may have another dependency chain like packageA -> packageD-v1 ->
>   packageC-v2

In this case, if `A` uses types from `C-v1`, how is this supposed to work? I can see only two possibilities:

1. `A` does not need types from `C` when using `packageD`. (by the way, why does it need `C` types for using `packageB` then?)
2. `C` types did not change, so `C` types from `C-v1` are compatible with `C-v2`

The only solution I can see for both #1 and #2 is to split out types from `C` into separate package, for example  `C-types`, and make it a dev dependency of `A`.

The types in `C-types` should **not** be the `d.ts` files generated by TypeScript, these should be all the interfaces, types and enums (but not classes, classes are an implementation detail and should stay in `C`) from `C`, moved out into regular `.ts` file included in separate package.

You will have to publish `C-types` in npm repo in the same way as `C` is published, with generated `.d.ts` and empty `.js` files, for each version of `C`. I don't think having empty `.js` files is a problem, but if it is, you can just publish manually written `.d.ts` files (however I don't know to type-check them before publishing, without having another package using them). There's no need to publish `C-types` through [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) and have them in `@types` scope - it's a mere convention, not a requirement. You just have to tell everyone in your org to use `C-types` instead of `@types/C`.

You say that with this approach

> I can still see many issues with this approach in terms of version
>   mismatch, global declaration conflict, or namescope conflict (it is
>   also true in the DefinetelyTyped/types approach)

First things  first, having global declarations is strongly discouraged - modules were invented for a reason, and every name used anywhere should be explicitly imported from somewhere.

And if your `A` uses types from `C`, you will have exactly the same problems with versioning with different versions of `C`. Splitting types out of `C` will just make you think about these problems beforehand, instead of hoping that things will "just work".

Comment: Hey @artem I am thinking the same on separating types from the source code, and manually maintain the versions. I guess typescript team may think about this as well and it's also part of the reasons why `DefinetelyTyped/types` is needed. A lot of people just get the types from dependencies without thinking about versions -- that maybe ok for web applications, but definitely not library contributors. 

I would like to give it more time and hear more thoughts before accepting an answer. Thanks for your detailed explanation!